Android Emulator Fails to Ping google.com: "ping: unknown host google.com" while system ping works
I'm having an issue with internet connectivity on my Android emulator. When I try to run adb shell ping -c 4 google.com, I get the following error:
ping: unknown host google.com

However, when I ping google.com directly from my system (macOS) terminal, everything works fine. Here's what I've tried so far:
Added various DNS addresses in the emulator settings.
Restarted adb and the emulator multiple times.
Reinstalled adb and the Android Emulator, but nothing has resolved the issue.
Here are some logs related to network activity from adb logcat:
09-30 16:05:09.461  3544  4555 I ReactNativeJS: Network: Request: ID:5f3d098f-d095-449f-b73e-51e1f84b86a8 METHOD:POST URL: /monsterenergyqa.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_ropc
09-30 16:05:09.875  3544  6285 D TrafficStats: tagSocket(151) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
09-30 16:05:11.881  3544  6287 D TrafficStats: tagSocket(163) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
09-30 16:05:13.886  3544  6289 D TrafficStats: tagSocket(118) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
09-30 16:05:17.894  3544  6296 D TrafficStats: tagSocket(141) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1

Network Settings Analysis:
IP Addresses: Emulator has IP addresses 10.0.2.15 for eth0 and 10.0.2.16 for wlan0.
Routing: Routes for eth0 and wlan0 are correctly configured for the local network.
DNS: Executing ping on 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS) is successful, indicating that the network connection is functional up to the IP level, but DNS queries are not being executed.

Additionally, it is important to note that accessing and modifying network settings directly within the emulator is not possible. This limitation prevents any direct changes to DNS or other network configurations from within the emulator's system settings.
Possible Causes:

DNS servers are not configured or are incorrectly set in the emulator's network settings.
Issues with the network stack configuration within the emulator itself.

How to fix it?
Any help is appreciated.

Probably the DNSs you added are wrong. Or perhaps you have other problems. Can you ping IPs ?
